# search model of two database tables when select drop down list option and pass it to a controller in codeigniter php

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables on for users, and one for cases, I want my search form that contains a dropdown list selected item to pass it to a controller by using a model, so I can search the two tables at a time.

this is my form:

```
<form method="POST" action="'dashboard_c/search_engin_user/'.$this->uri->segment(3);?>" method="post">
<select id="dropdown" name="filter">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">User Name</option>
    <option value="2">Badge Number</option>
    <option value="3">Case Type</option>
    <option value="5">Case Date</option>
    <option value="6">Case Status</option>
    <option value="7">Case User</option>
</select>


<!--search bar for search term input -->

<input id="search" type="text" name="search" value="" />
<input id="submit" type ="submit" name ="filter" value ="Search">

</form>
```

And in my model I tried to wrote this to join the two tables:

```
function search($search_term) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->join('cases', 'cases.user_id = user.id');
    $this->db->like('user.username', $search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('user.badge_number', $search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('cases.type', $search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('cases.date', $search_term);
    $this->db->or_like('cases.statuse', $search_term);
    $this->db->group_by("user.id");
    return $this->db->get();
    //$qu = $query->result_array();
}
```

I also tried to put two models and each search of table in one separated model.

This is my controller, but I have no result since i'm filtering two tables in one mode and one form

```
 public function search_engin_user()
{
    $this->load->model('users_m');
    $this->load->model('cases');
    $filter = $this->input->post('filter');
    $field  = $this->input->post('field');
    //$field2  = $this->input->post('field2');
    $data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data['subview'] = 'include/d_header';
    $search_term = $this->input->post('search');
    if(isset($filter)and !empty($search_term)){
        $this->users_m->getUsersSearch($field,$search_term);
        redirect("dashboard_c/show_user/" . $this->uri->segment(3));

    }
```

I want to know how should I pass the dropdown selected option to a controller and having one model to process the two tables and the result will show in two different views one to show user and one to show the case I searched for.

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: You have a form and a query, which you say works fine. What is your actual issue? Is it how to use controllers? How to call models? How to get posted form values? Please show us your attempt and let us know more specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: read about controllers: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html

Comment: I have no result yet, I searched for an example similar to what I need and I didnt find one, I think my model and my controller need more editing

Comment: You're calling `$this->users_m->getUsersSearch($field,$search_term);` while showing us the method `search()`? How are they related? You should also insert a bunch of `var_dump()` on the variables you're trying to pass around to see if they are correct.

Comment: I suspect your problem is the way you have your logic structured.  Your form is passing the search off to another controller function (search_engin_user), and yet you aren't returning that variable to the original controller function where the search view is (search)...you are just trying to do a redirect.  Beyond that, first test to make sure the search query in the model works without passing it off to a view.  You can setup a manual unit test and dump the search results to make sure that portion is working.  Then you can restructure your logic.

Comment: Both your drop down and submit button has the name `filter` in your form. I'm guessing that the drop down is suppose to be `field`? This means that `$field` will always be null. Not that I can see that you're actually using that variable anywhere, except passing it to the method `getUsersSearch()`, of which we know nothing about. You should start by going through your script and make sure that all values are what you expect and has the correct names. There are too many unknowns and errors for us to be able to help.